# vkey from the url cannot be get in the controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making this forgot password where the user will first input their email then an email link will be sent and if it is clicked it will go to the change password page. Only a new password and retype password exists on this page.

**changepassword.blade.php**

```
<form id="loginform" action='verifyReset' method='POST'>
    @csrf
    @if(session()->has('message'))
        <div class="alert-danger" style="color:#FF0000;">
            {{ session()->get('message') }}
        </div>
    @endif
    @if(session()->has('emessage'))
        <div class="alert-danger" style="color:#00FF00;">
            {{ session()->get('emessage') }}
        </div>
    @endif
    <label id= "loginlabel" for="newpassword">  <p style="font-family:'Montserrat'; font-size: 15px; text-align: left;"> New Password:   </p></label>
    <input id="logininput" type="text" id="password" name="password" placeholder="********">
    <br>
    <label id= "loginlabel" for="rtnewpassword">  <p style="font-family:'Montserrat'; font-size: 15px; text-align: left;"> Re-Type<br> New Password:</p></label>
    <input id="logininput" type="text" id="rtpassword" name="rtpassword" placeholder="********">
    <br><br><br>
    <button style="text-align:center" type="submit" class="login-btn">Enter</button>
</form>
```

This page will have a URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/verifyReset?vkey=83b32b72b240ce6330e5062ad9ad5ae306a529b0

**Controller**

```
public function verifyReset(Request $request) {
    $vkey = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::get('vkey');
    $pass = $request->password;
    $rtpass = $request->rtpassword;
    if (!empty($pass)&&!empty($rtpass)) {
        if($pass == $rtpass) {
             $update = DB::table('users')
                ->where('vkey', $vkey)
                ->update(['password' => bcrypt($pass)]);
            if($update) {
                return redirect()->back()->with('emessage', 'Pass');
            } else {
                return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Fail');
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Password does not match');
        }
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Input fields must be filled up');
    }
```

What I wanted to do was to get that vkey from the URL as a basis on what account will be changed but when I echo the $vkey it shows nothing. I have tried this function on a get method form and it worked. does this form, which has a post method, prevents the controller to get the vkey? or do I need to change something?

Comment: `$vkey = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::get('vkey');` to `$vkey = request('vkey')`

Comment: i tried it but its still the same. it passes to the fail message

Comment: if your route path is correct, try using `$request->input('vkey')` to get

Comment: helllo . sorrry but its still the same. is there maybe a way on an alternative way to do a forgot password. I've been thinking of putting an email input but what if user puts an email that is not their email.

Comment: can you check `dd(request('vkey'))` in this url  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/verifyReset?vkey=83b32b72b240ce6330e5062ad9ad5ae306a529b0` as here your passing `vkey`

Comment: it redirects to this url : http://127.0.0.1:8000/verifyReset and a word "null" shows